# UITableView returning from a detail view and updating mainview cell HELP

Tags: uitableview, view, reload, tableview

So i drill down from main view (which is populated by an APPDelegate array) into a detail view. In that view i can edit the app Delegate array, which i do, then when i return my cell is the previous value not the new value.  i use

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[self mainTableView] reloadData];      
}
```

But on appearance it's not updated, but as soon as the cell gets recycled (ie. scroll up then down) it appears fine. I think it's just late and im missing something simple.... wop wop woaaaaa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote my own refresh-methode and call it by myself before I `pop` or `push` the `UIViewController`:

```
- (void)reset {
    // refresh:
    UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *) self.view;
    [tableView reloadData]; 
}
```

Comment: thanks! But i did find the answer somewhere on here... i think i wasn't initializing the Table view on load properly.